# Unable to start haproxy 2.4 - Missing LF on last line?

Tags: installation, makefile, configuration, haproxy

Basically the title.  I'm working on upgrading our existing haproxy from 1.5 to the latest version.  Because of that, I'm setting up a test case to ensure our old setup can work on it.  However, when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
[NOTICE]   (28948) : haproxy version is 2.4.1-1ce7d49
[NOTICE]   (28948) : path to executable is /home/user/test/usr/local/sbin/haproxy
[ALERT]    (28948) : parsing [test.cfg:22]: Missing LF on last line, file might have been truncated at position 68.
[ALERT]    (28948) : Error(s) found in configuration file : test.cfg
[ALERT]    (28948) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

I've tried looking it up, but I cannot find anything on the error.  I've already checked my config file, and it is using the correct Unix format.  Also, my test config works for the older version of HAProxy.

```
global
   stats timeout 30s
   user root
   group root

defaults
   log global
   mode http
   option httplog
   option dontlognull
   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 50000
   timeout server 50000

frontend http_front
   bind *:9090
   default_backend http_back

backend http_back
   balance roundrobin
   server test.server.com 127.0.0.1:8000
```

In addition, I did the following to install haproxy:

```
tar xvf haproxy-2.4.1.tar.gz
cd haproxy-2.4.1
#vi to Makefile and set PREFIX to PREFIX = /home/user/test/usr/local
make TARGET=linux-glibc
make install
```

Is there anything that sticks out regarding my config file?  Or did I miss something in the installation process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you truncated your config file somehow. It looks ok.
I wasn't testing it on 2.4, but i found reference to it: https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg37698.html and was able to reproduce it on 2.2 (it was warning in 2.2, became error in 2.3 as described by haproxy message) with this simple config:

```
defaults
   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 50000
   timeout server 50000

frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   mode http
   http-request deny
```

This config is valid:

```
# haproxy -c -f test.conf
Configuration file is valid
```

Now i will truncate it by one byte to reproduce it:

```
# wc -c test.conf
149 test.conf
# dd if=test.conf of=test2.conf bs=1 count=148
148+0 records in
148+0 records out
148 bytes copied, 0.00267937 s, 55.2 kB/s
# hexdump -C test.conf
00000000  64 65 66 61 75 6c 74 73  0a 20 20 20 74 69 6d 65  |defaults.   time|
00000010  6f 75 74 20 63 6f 6e 6e  65 63 74 20 35 30 30 30  |out connect 5000|
00000020  0a 20 20 20 74 69 6d 65  6f 75 74 20 63 6c 69 65  |.   timeout clie|
00000030  6e 74 20 35 30 30 30 30  0a 20 20 20 74 69 6d 65  |nt 50000.   time|
00000040  6f 75 74 20 73 65 72 76  65 72 20 35 30 30 30 30  |out server 50000|
00000050  0a 0a 66 72 6f 6e 74 65  6e 64 20 68 74 74 70 5f  |..frontend http_|
00000060  66 72 6f 6e 74 0a 20 20  20 62 69 6e 64 20 2a 3a  |front.   bind *:|
00000070  38 30 0a 20 20 20 6d 6f  64 65 20 68 74 74 70 0a  |80.   mode http.|
00000080  20 20 20 68 74 74 70 2d  72 65 71 75 65 73 74 20  |   http-request |
00000090  64 65 6e 79 0a                                    |deny.|
00000095
# hexdump -C test2.conf
00000000  64 65 66 61 75 6c 74 73  0a 20 20 20 74 69 6d 65  |defaults.   time|
00000010  6f 75 74 20 63 6f 6e 6e  65 63 74 20 35 30 30 30  |out connect 5000|
00000020  0a 20 20 20 74 69 6d 65  6f 75 74 20 63 6c 69 65  |.   timeout clie|
00000030  6e 74 20 35 30 30 30 30  0a 20 20 20 74 69 6d 65  |nt 50000.   time|
00000040  6f 75 74 20 73 65 72 76  65 72 20 35 30 30 30 30  |out server 50000|
00000050  0a 0a 66 72 6f 6e 74 65  6e 64 20 68 74 74 70 5f  |..frontend http_|
00000060  66 72 6f 6e 74 0a 20 20  20 62 69 6e 64 20 2a 3a  |front.   bind *:|
00000070  38 30 0a 20 20 20 6d 6f  64 65 20 68 74 74 70 0a  |80.   mode http.|
00000080  20 20 20 68 74 74 70 2d  72 65 71 75 65 73 74 20  |   http-request |
00000090  64 65 6e 79                                       |deny|
00000094
# haproxy -c -f test2.conf
[WARNING] 193/184514 (10725) : parsing [test2.conf:9]: Missing LF on last line, file might have been truncated at position 21. This will become a hard error in HAProxy 2.3.
Warnings were found.
Configuration file is valid
```

Note the missing `0a` at the end. Check your config with `hexdump -C`

Comment: That worked.  I ended up remaking the file, and adding a newline to the end, and it started up fine.  Thank you

Comment: Had the exact same issue with 2.4 (`2.4.2-553dee3`) version using the official Docker image `haproxy`.
Debugged for 2 hours straight until I stumbled upon this question, and fixed it just by adding a newline at the end of file.

I thought I was losing my mind since the exact same code and config file are working on another machine, with just, I guess, an empty line on the end.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and I tried using Editor. but, it didn't work.
I was able to solve this issue by adding a new line.
I used the echo command and it worked.

```
echo "" >> /etc/hapee-2.2/hapee-lb.cfg
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue when running HAproxy on **Windows Docker**.

After turning on `Show All Characters` from the icons on the top in Notepad ++ (In the view menu -> Show symbols - Show All Characters) , I could see that the last line was missing a new line control character.

(On Windows, either CRLF or LF, both works fine)

[image]

Based on other answers in this thread, proceeded to add a new line by simply hitting enter key after the last character in the config file.

[image]

But noticed same error.

`parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:28]: Missing LF on last line, file might have been truncated at position 3. Missing LF on last line, file might have been truncated at position 3.`

After some trial and error, I got it to work with below changes.
[image]

**Ensure that the last character of the config file is either CRLF or LF.** If there are additional spaces, then remove those (in my case notepad++ added two spaces for auto indentation which was causing the issue even after adding a new line).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue using Rancher when deploying Bitnami HAproxy. I quickly found that the constructor was addinng |- [block chomping indicator](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2-old/spec.html#id2794534) removing the '0a' at the end. I had to edit the file in yaml format making sure to remove this indicator.

*example:*

```
config: |-
  defalts
    timeout.....
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
frontend http
    bind *:8080
    mode http
    timeout client 10s
    use_backend all

backend all
    mode http
    server s0 nodeapp0:3000
    server s1 nodeapp1:3001
```

**NOTE:** Use some newlines (using enter) in your config file. here is my simple cfg file, I used enter keys to deal with the error.

[image]

#### Working Solution:

- 

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: just an update from other answers.

Indeed that we just need to adding a newline to the end of the `haproxy.cfg` and it's gonna be okay.

But if you using `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` to build and deploy haproxy on docker, please note this:

Whenever you change the `haproxy.cfg` on your local machine, try to remove the image of haproxy builded by `Dockerfile` first, then re-run the `docker compose up -d` command.

The purpose of this is to reload the haproxy image builded by `Dockerfile` so it will apply your change to the image.

I know this because i tried to run `docker compose down`, `docker compose up -d` or even `docker compose restart` sereval time and the issue is still there.

Took me 2 hours to find this, hope it helped some one.