# haproxy configuration file issues Missing LF on last line, file might have been truncated at position

Tags: docker, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I followed a recently written article (Aug 9, 2021) on haproxy website, supposedly on how to run haproxy in docker

https://www.haproxy.com/blog/how-to-run-haproxy-with-docker/

i followed this guide and i have the following `haproxy.cfg`

```
global
  stats socket /var/run/api.sock user haproxy group haproxy mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
  log stdout format raw local0 info

defaults
  mode http
  timeout client 10s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout server 10s
  timeout http-request 10s
  log global

frontend stats
  bind *:8404
  stats enable
  stats uri /
  stats refresh 10s

frontend myfrontend
  bind :80
  default_backend webservers

backend webservers
  server s1 jmalloc-1:8080 check
  server s2 jmalloc-2:8080 check
  server s3 jmalloc-3:8080 check
```

but i am getting these errors

```
haproxy  | [NOTICE]   (1) : haproxy version is 2.4.17-9f97155
haproxy  | [ALERT]    (1) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:26]: Missing LF on last line, file might have been truncated at position 33.
haproxy  | [ALERT]    (1) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
haproxy  | [ALERT]    (1) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
haproxy  | [NOTICE]   (1) : haproxy version is 2.4.17-9f97155
haproxy  | [ALERT]    (1) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:26]: Missing LF on last line, file might have been truncated at position 33.
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350378/unable-to-start-haproxy-2-4-missing-lf-on-last-line

(TL;DR : the fix is to recreate the file)

Answer (score 0):

As Imsec mentioned, this is a duplicate of [Unable to start haproxy 2.4 - Missing LF on last line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350378/unable-to-start-haproxy-2-4-missing-lf-on-last-line).

In the case you are using Kubernetes though, what fixed the problem for me was removing the chomp indicator to retain the new line at the end of the file when it was created.

I.e not-working

```
data:
  haproxy.cfg: |-
    global
        {{- range .Values.haproxy_conf.globals }}
        {{ . }}
        {{- end }}
...
```

Working:

```
  haproxy.cfg: |
    global
        {{- range .Values.haproxy_conf.globals }}
        {{ . }}
        {{- end }}
...
```

If you are not using a config map and copying it into your dockerfile, simply just adding a new line to your eof or adding it in through an entrypoint or run command should suffice

Comment: i moved on really from haproxy and just went with a more modern and better reverse proxy in traefik; haproxy is old tech now and even the non-working "official" guide shows that

Comment: Nice, yea I've used Traefik and I like it. I feel its a bit more cleaner then nginx as well if you are managing things through manifests.

Comment: traefik is pretty much taking over; nothing much really to say. nginx and haproxy are more for static setup, traefik take care of dynamic stuffs AND static stuffs for people that love static...traefik to me has won the reverse proxy war hands down